# Where to put a module descriptor for the default module?

Tags: ceylon

I have chosen to put the code of my small project in the 'default' module (in the file /source/main.ceylon), but where do I then place my module descriptor?
Currently I have it in /source/module.ceylon
but that gives me the dire warning "module descriptor encountered in root source directory" when holding the mouse over the module name.

I need to have a module descriptor, as I need to depend on a Ceylon module (`httpd`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default module cannot have a module descriptor, and therefore cannot have dependencies. While the default module can be useful for quick hello world type programs, it's generally recommended to have a proper named module.